# debugging java web application

Tags: java, debugging, jsp, servlets

I have a third party application which has lot of servlets and jsp. I wanted to debug that by putting breakpoints on my local jboss server. How do I know that, for a particular request, the request is being processed by particular java classes and jsp, so that I can put breakpoints in the right files? I am thinking of going through the code, before setting the breakpoints, to know where to put them. But I feel this is not an efficient way to do it (as it is a very big application). Can you please suggest if there is any better way to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The web.xml file contains `servlet-mapping` elements indicating which servlets are mapped to which URLs. So if you know the URL, you should easily find the corresponding servlet. Now you can read the servlet code to see which other classes are involved.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have followed the same. initially went through the web.xml and  and looked into servelet and also classes (invoked by servlet) and did set the breakpoints. when  i start the debugging it is going fine some level(like loading required .xml files),execution is not entering into actual servlets and java classes .then  its again asking me to attach the source code( actully i am doing kind of remote debugging , starting the server in debug mode then attaching sourcd code in eclipse). then i tried to attach the source code again, but getting issue

Answer (score 0):

I think fastest way for debugging applications like this, is profiling application for specific usecase, in this way you can understand which classes used for this scenario and after finding classes, you can debug these classes.

for profiling application there are lots of tools.

**commercial**: [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/), [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/index.html), [JProbe](https://support.quest.com/jprobe/9.7)

**open source**:[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), [Javacalltracer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacalltracer/) (create run-time sequence diagram)